# All the nodes in Tree not getting expanded

Tags: java, treeview, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to learn TreeViewer in RCP. I wrote this small piece of code for that.

```
public class TreeViewClass extends ViewPart {

public static final String ID = "TreeViewerDemo.treeView";

public TreeViewClass() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();

    TreeItem root = new TreeItem(tree, 0);
    root.setText("Root Node");

    TreeItem childNode1 = new TreeItem(root, 0);
    childNode1.setText("Child Node 1");

    TreeItem childNode2 = new TreeItem(childNode1, 0);
    childNode2.setText("Child Node 2");
}

@Override
public void setFocus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

When I am running this code, The tree gets displayed, but only the root node. When I click on the root node(with a arrow icon, which means it has children), the node does not display the children nodes. 
Later I discovered that, when I apply setExpanded(true) to a node, it gets displayed, otherwise, it doesn't.

Where is the problem in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `TreeViewer` you should not use `TreeItem`. Instead you use a content provider and label provider. If you want to use `TreeItem` use `Tree`. Mixing the two will give unpredictable results.

Comment: Thanks a lot greg! Can you please provide an example using tree and Treeitem. I made a mess while trying to do so. So I was trying to use treeviewer. I would be grateful! Thanksa  again!

Comment: I think just doing `new Tree` instead of TreeViewer is the only change. If you want nodes to be expanded you have to call `setExpanded`.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I am now able to do it...Did just as you said!.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `TreeViewer` you should not use `TreeItem`. Instead you use a content provider and label provider. If you want to use `TreeItem` use `Tree`. Mixing the two will give unpredictable results.

When using `TreeItem` you need to call `setExpanded(true)` on each item you want to be expanded.